# JSON Parsing Android, boolean

Tags: php, android, json, parsing

I've got a code in my android app:
[image]

And when I'm sending a response with php when error is false, like this:

```
$response["error"] = false;
$response["user"] = $user;
```

Everything is ok, and it starts MainActivity. But when error is true:

```
$response["error"] = true;
$response["message"] = "User don't exist!";
```

I'm getting an error on my device:

> value true at error of type java.lang.Boolean cannot be converted to JSONObject

How it's possible that with false value it works, but with true dont?

Comment: You're not sending JSON back to your android app. Use `json_encode($response);`

Comment: is it because $response["message"] = "User don't exist!"; ?

Comment: I'm sending json_encode($response);

Comment: @DanielKoczuła Wrong parsing in else condition where you are displaying Toast. Please see my answer.

Comment: F.y.i. please avoid pasting code as an image, the formatting features of SO are pretty cool, code like this would be easier to read and search for as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong parsing in `else` condition where you are displaying `Toast`.

In your `Toast` message in `else` condition

Change

```
obj.getJSONObject("error").getString("message")
```

to

```
obj.getString("message")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the line, in the else condition where you show the toast message :

```
obj.getJSONObject("error").getString("message") ;
```

to

```
obj.getString("message") ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is here, where you make a Toast displaying the login error message:

```
obj.getJSONObject("error").getString("message")
```

Just try:

```
obj.getString("message")
```

instead if you want to display the error message, because obj is already a JSONObject.